# Android rawQuery result check

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, mobile

I searched over and over in order to find answer to this question but you are my only chance.
Here is the thing:

I have a DBAdapter class, MakeListActivity and SeeListActivity.

In DBAdapter I made a following method:

```
public Cursor commitQuery(String query)
{
    return myDataBase.rawQuery(query,null);
}
```

MakeListActivity have the following method:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO list('name','description') VALUES('"+name+"','"+desc+"')";
dbAdapter.commitQuery(query);
```

and finally, SeeListActivity has the following code:

```
Cursor c = dbAdapter.commitQuery("SELECT * FROM list");
if(c!=null)
{
    c.moveToFirst();
    Log.i("cursor",c.getString(1));
}
```

I'm actually not sure if I inserted data correctly, but when i want to see data(in my case log it with logcat) I get "Unfortunately, com.dstankovic.app has stopped."

Here is also logcat error:

```
    02-26 00:31:11.762: E/AndroidRuntime(660): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-26 00:31:11.762: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
02-26 00:31:11.762: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
02-26 00:31:11.762: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
02-26 00:31:11.762: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-26 00:31:11.762: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-26 00:31:11.762: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-26 00:31:11.762: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-26 00:31:11.762: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 00:31:11.762: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-26 00:31:11.762: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-26 00:31:11.762: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-26 00:31:11.762: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-26 00:31:11.762: E/AndroidRuntime(660): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-26 00:31:11.762: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 00:31:11.762: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-26 00:31:11.762: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
02-26 00:31:11.762: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  ... 11 more
02-26 00:31:11.762: E/AndroidRuntime(660): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
02-26 00:31:11.762: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
02-26 00:31:11.762: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
02-26 00:31:11.762: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
02-26 00:31:11.762: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at com.dulerock.eatwell.MakeNewListActivity.SaveList(MakeNewListActivity.java:278)
```

Can someone give me a hint on this? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Start by finding the first line in the stacktrace which refers to a class that you have the code for.

Comment: @Dušan Stanković check my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here cursor is not null but it has not data...you need to make sure that there is a data in the cursor

`moveToFirst()` return true if there is a data in the cursor and false if it is empty

try this

```
Cursor c = dbAdapter.commitQuery("SELECT * FROM list");
if(c.moveToFirst())
{
   Log.i("cursor",c.getString(1));
}
```

Comment: As i mentioned in comment above, this c.moveToFirst() is not true. Is it possible that inserting into db was wrong even if it doesn't throw any errors? Thanks

Comment: This means your cursor doesn't contain any data...So there is a problem in your insert

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to figure out how to check if my insert query did the job. When I execute query it seems fine, don't throw any error, but later when i want to read data, as we saw, cursor is empty...

Comment: Maybe i should try using execSQL instead of rawQuery?

Comment: You can use raw query but There is something wrong with your query string..Try to insert using exexSQL and then check whether the problem is because of query or any other

Comment: I tried execSQL() and it worked fine! I just don't realize why it didn't accept rawQuery()? Thank you so much for discussion. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming that because you got a Cursor you have elements:

```
Cursor c = dbAdapter.commitQuery("SELECT * FROM list");
if(c!=null)
{
    c.moveToFirst();
    Log.i("cursor",c.getString(1));
}
```

Try to check if `c.moveToFirst()` returned true first.

Comment: I tried, it's apparently empty... how can i be sure that i inserted data into table correctly? Thanks